# Typescript dynamic type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want the interface Key to be able to infer the type of items in the onChange method from the format value. Whether this idea works in typescript.

```
interface Key<T extends Record<string, any>> {
    format?: keyof T;

    items: T[];

    /** The items parameter waits to be inferred */
    onChange(items): void;
}

interface Datum {
    value: {
        inner: string;
    };
}

type NoFormatKeyExpect = Datum;

const noFormatKey: Key<Datum> = {
    items: [{ value: { inner: "Hello" } }],

    onChange(items) {
        /** If the object has no format property, I want items to be inferred as an array of NoFormatKeyExpect. */
    },
};

interface HasFormatKeyExpect {
    inner: Datum["value"]["inner"];
}

const hasFormatKey: Key<Datum> = {
    format: "value",

    items: [{ value: { inner: "Hello" } }],

    onChange(items) {
        /** If the object has format property, I want items to be inferred as an array of HasFormatKeyExpect. */
    },
};
```

I want code hint when I write hasFormatKey onChange method. How do I write the interface Key?

---

---

Let me simplify the example a little bit.

```
type ItemInfer<T, F> = F extends keyof T ? Pick<T, F> : T

interface ListProps<T extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>, F extends keyof T = keyof T> {
    format?: F
    
    onChange?(items: ItemInfer<T, F>): void
}


// If i dont't write the second generic, the item of the onChange method has no code hints.
// Is there a way to get code hints without writing a second generic?
const demo1: ListProps<{ a: string; b: number }> = {
    format: 'b',
    onChange(item) {
        // Why can't item be inferred to be {b:number}.
        item.b // There is no code hint for item here
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be for you to implement a switch case and check the item type, something like:

```
onChange(items) {
        /** If the object has no format property, I want items to be inferred as an array of NoFormatKeyExpect. */
        switch(items){
            case Array:
                console.log("It`s an array");
                break;
            case Number:
                console.log("It`s a number");
                break;
            case String:
                console.log("It`s a string");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    },
```

And you could also apply the Strategy design pattern (I think), which would be to create a generic and abstract implementation for items `ItemsInterface`, and item extensions, like `ItemOne`, and in your `onChange` function each item calls an abstract method to be implemented in the item extensions.

```
onChange(items: ItemInterface) {
        /** If the object has no format property, I want items to be inferred as an array of NoFormatKeyExpect. */
        items.onChange()
    },
```

Comment: I want the compiler to infer this type rather than judge it in the onChange method.@Maykon Meneghel

Comment: I'm sorry, although your title is quite clear, I didn't understand it at first, and I thought it was a superficial problem. Disregard my answer. I will try to edit based on a correct solution. But first, let me know how you instantiate your key, or whatever it is you'd like to initialize. Can you tell me what you call this interface, or at least, would you like to call it?

Comment: I've simplified an example. If you don't know anything, please ask me again

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your problem. But I was able to make the 'b' property of the item assume a type of 'any', during compilation, by simply changing the signature to `const demo1: ListProps<{ a: string; b: number }, any> = { ... }`. This doesn't work, since the type of property 'b' is number and not any. Something tells me that the problem is in the logic of the templates, I'll research better how to reformulate its structure. Take it easy, let's solve this together =)